# Converting VM Subscription to not include sql

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a VM running on Azure running an A2 subscription with SQL Standard.
Is there a way to remove SQL standard from the subscription?
Do I have to spin up a new instance and migrate everything across?

Comment: Hi, your VM is A2 size and you install SQL inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you need create a new instance and migrate your data to your new VM. If not, you will continue pay for SQL.

More information about see please check [price calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

VM + SQL

[image]

Only VM

[image]